# Recurrence relation for given algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, time-complexity, recurrence

```
int print4Subtree(struct Node *root) {
    if (root == NULL)
      return 0;
    int l =  print4Subtree(root->left);
    int r =   print4Subtree(root->right);
    if ((l + r + 1) == 4)
       printf("%d ", root->data);
    return (l + r + 1); }
```

---

This algorithm/code finds number of subtrees having exactly 4 nodes in binary tree , it's works in bottom-up manner .
I know the time complexity of this code would be O(n) , and space complexity is O(log n) , since it's using recursion.

> What will be recurrence relation for the code ?

I try to draw  T(n) = 2T(n-1)+1 , which is obviously wrong !

Comment: In the recurrence relation, `n` is not an integer. It must be a tree. Then, `T(n) = 1 + T(n.left) + T(n.right)`. Formally, it does not only depend on the number of nodes but also on their structure.

Comment: Your formula `T(n) =  2T(n-1)+1`, this `n` is not the number of nodes. You can use it only when the tree is balanced binary tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only talk about recurrence relations in terms of *n* alone in cases where you know more about the structure of the tree, for instance:

**Case 1:** Every node has only one child meaning 
*T*(*n*) = *T*(0) + *T*(*n*-1) + *k*. 
**Case 2:** Subtrees at any level are balanced so that
*T*(*n*) = 2 *T*((*n*-1)/2) + *k*.

Both of these will result in O(*n*), but these two cases are only a very select minority of possible trees. For a more universal approach you have to use a formula like *T*(*n*) = *T*(*a*) + *T*(*b*), where *a* and *b* are an arbitrary division into sub-problems resulting from the structure of your tree. You can still establish results from this kind of formula using [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction).

The following is the exact formula and approach I would use:
*T*(*n*) = *nk* + *m<sub>n</sub>c*, where *m<sub>n</sub>* ≤ *n* + 1. (Note: I am using *k* for overhead of recursive steps and *c* for overhead of base/null steps).

**Base case (*n*=0):**
 For a null node *T*(0) = *c* so *T*(*n*) = *kn* + *m<sub>n</sub>c* ,
 where *m<sub>n</sub>* = 1 ≤ *n*+1 = 1.
**Inductive step (*T*(*x*) = *xk* + *m<sub>x</sub>c* for all *x* < *n*):**
The sub_tree of size *n* has two sub-trees of sizes *a* and *b* (*a* or *b* may be 0) such that *n* = *a* + *b* + 1.
*T*(*n*) = *T*(*a*) + *T*(*b*) + *k* = *ak* + *m<sub>a</sub>c* + *bk* + *m<sub>b</sub>c* + *k* = (*a*+*b*+1)*k* + (*m<sub>a</sub>*+*m<sub>b</sub>*)*c* = *nk* + *m<sub>n</sub>c* ,
where *m<sub>n</sub>* = *m<sub>a</sub>* + *m<sub>b</sub>* ≤ *a* + 1 + *b* + 1 = *n* + 1.

The reason for using *m<sub>n</sub>* is merely a formality to make the proof smoother, as the exact number of null cases is what is actually affected by the structure of tree (in the former case 2, it is log *n*). So *T*(*n*) is at best O(*n*) because of the *nk* term, and can be no worst than O(*n*) because of the bound on *m<sub>n</sub>c*.